# How to mimic Sublime Text's HTML dom completion in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Currently in Sublime Text 2 I can do the following while editing a .html file:

```
hr.margin-none <TAB>
```

and it will expand automatically to

```
<hr class="margin-none"></hr>
```

Is there a similar function in Emacs? I found something on Flexible Expand but it doesn't seem to do what I was hoping (or maybe I'm just using it wrong.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same thing in Emacs. Just install the `emmet-mode` and enable it. Reading the following page would help you.

https://github.com/smihica/emmet-mode

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Need to investigate whether it's feasible to replace C-j with TAB... that's what I'm used to and old habits die hard. Thanks!